# Kubernetes HPA custom scaling rules

Tags: kubernetes

I have a master-slave-like deployment, when the first pod starts (master node) it will be running on more powerful nodes and slaves on less powerful ones.

I am doing it using affinity/anti-affinity.

Since both of them run the exact same binaries, I wanted to set to the autoscaler (HPA) some custom policy for the first and the other nodes, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Do you want to use HPA also for the pod on the master node? And what is the purpose for custom policy, since you already have an affinity / anti-affinity solution? Maybe you can provide an example of your vision?

Comment: I have a deployment with HPA set, first pod will always run on node type #1 and all the secondary pods (pod 2, 3, 4..) will run on node type #2

Comment: Sorry for delay. Is there any progress in solving this problem?

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using, how was it deployed? Are you using original Kubernetes or something special - OpenShift, Rancher, etc.? In the question, you mentioned about usage of affinity / anti-affinity. Are you able to run 1st pod on the Master node and next 2, 3, 4 ... pods on the worker node (only one)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it.
You can write your own custom metric to support your desired logic

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/custom-and-external-metrics

You can also use projects like https://keda.sh/

Comment: Thanks but unless I misunderstood the concept, that's not exactly what I need. I am saying that for example I have an HPA minReplicas: 2 and maxReplicas: 5. 1 pod will be created on the stronger node (affinity #1) and the second on will be created on the weaker node (affinity #2)